# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xc5' in position 35: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, django, encoding, utf-8, django-admin

I am currently using [Django-countries](https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries) to get a list of ISO country names for a form field. It displays without error on my website, but on Django's Admin site it causes the aforementioned error due to the presence of non-ASCII country names:

> Unicode error hint: The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: itan Åland

I've read that similar problems can be settled with the `encode('utf-8')` attribute, but this does not seem very feasible without having to touch Django Admin itself. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone has a solution to this problem.

Models.py(messages):

```
    from __future__ import unicode_literals
    from django.db import models
    from auth.models import User
    from tourlisting.models import Tour

    class Itinerary(models.Model):
        start_date = models.DateField()
        end_date = models.DateField()

        def __str__(self):
            return "Itinerary " + str(self.id)

    class TourActivity(models.Model):
        start_time = models.DateTimeField()
        end_time = models.DateTimeField()
        description = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')
        location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        itinerary = models.ForeignKey(Itinerary)

    class ThreadManager(models.Manager):
        def create_thread(self, tour, itinerary, traveller):
            thread = self.create(tour=tour, itinerary=itinerary, traveller=traveller)
            return thread

    class Thread(models.Model):
        tour = models.ForeignKey(Tour)
        itinerary = models.ForeignKey(Itinerary, null=True)
        traveller = models.ForeignKey(User)
        objects = ThreadManager()

        def __str__(self):
            return "Thread " + str(self.id)

    class Message(models.Model):
        message = models.TextField()
        sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sent_messages')
        thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
        time_sent = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        time_read = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Models.py(tourlisting):

```
    from __future__ import unicode_literals
    from django.db import models
    from auth.models import UserProfile, User
    from djmoney.models.fields import MoneyField
    from django.utils import timezone
    from django_countries.fields import CountryField
    import datetime

    class Category(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    class Tour(models.Model):
        tour_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
        tour_desc = models.CharField('Tour Description', max_length=10000, default='')
        tour_guide = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
        tour_length = models.IntegerField('Tour length (days)', default = 3)
        country = CountryField(default='', max_length=100)
        city = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='')
        ppl_min = models.IntegerField('Minimum no. of travellers', default=1)
        ppl_max = models.IntegerField('Maximum no. if travellers', default=10)
        price = MoneyField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD', default=50)
        category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
        pub_date = models.DateField('date published', auto_now_add=True)
        active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        def __str__(self):
            return "{0} by {1}".format(self.tour_name, self.tour_guide)
        def was_listed_recently(self):
            return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
```

Stack trace:

```
    Environment:


    Request Method: GET
    Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/messaging/thread/2/change/

    Django Version: 1.9.2
    Python Version: 2.7.10
    Installed Applications:
    ('django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.sites',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'messaging',
     'crispy_forms',
     'djmoney',
     'django_countries',
     'haystack',
     'pysolr',
     'django_tables2',
     'phonenumber_field',
     'django_extensions')
    Installed Middleware:
    ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


    Template error:
    In template /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html, error at line 33
       ascii   23 : {% endblock %}
       24 : {% endif %}
       25 : 
       26 : {% block content %}
       27 : {% block object-tools %}
       28 : {% if change %}{% if not is_popup %}
       29 :   
       30 :     {% block object-tools-items %}
       31 :     
       32 :         {% url opts|admin_urlname:'history' original.pk|admin_urlquote as history_url %}
       33 :         {% trans "History" %}
       34 :     
       35 :     {% if has_absolute_url %}{% trans "View on site" %}{% endif %}
       36 :     {% endblock %}
       37 :   
       38 : {% endif %}{% endif %}
       39 : {% endblock %}
       40 : {% csrf_token %}{% block form_top %}{% endblock %}
       41 : 
       42 : {% if is_popup %}{% endif %}
       43 : {% if to_field %}{% endif %}


    Traceback:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
      174.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
      172.                     response = response.render()

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
      160.             self.content = self.rendered_content

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
      137.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
      95.             return self.template.render(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
      206.                     return self._render(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
      197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
      992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
      959.             return self.render(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
      173.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
      197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
      992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
      959.             return self.render(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
      173.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
      197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
      992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
      959.             return self.render(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
      69.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
      992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
      959.             return self.render(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
      69.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
      992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
      959.             return self.render(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
      220.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
      959.             return self.render(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
      209.                 return template.render(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
      208.                 return self._render(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
      197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
      992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
      959.             return self.render(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
      220.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
      959.             return self.render(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
      220.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
      959.             return self.render(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
      326.                 return nodelist.render(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
      992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
      959.             return self.render(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
      326.                 return nodelist.render(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
      992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
      959.             return self.render(context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
      1049.         return render_value_in_context(output, context)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_value_in_context
      1026.     value = force_text(value)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/encoding.py" in force_text
      78.                 s = six.text_type(s)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/html.py" in 
      381.         klass.__unicode__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_unicode(self))

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py" in __str__
      43.         return self.as_widget()

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py" in as_widget
      101.         return force_text(widget.render(name, self.value(), attrs=attrs))

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py" in render
      291.             'widget': self.widget.render(name, value, *args, **kwargs),

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/widgets.py" in render
      528.         options = self.render_options(choices, [value])

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/widgets.py" in render_options
      554.         for option_value, option_label in chain(self.choices, choices):

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py" in __iter__
      1110.             yield self.choice(obj)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py" in choice
      1117.         return (self.field.prepare_value(obj), self.field.label_from_instance(obj))

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py" in label_from_instance
      1180.         return smart_text(obj)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/encoding.py" in smart_text
      42.     return force_text(s, encoding, strings_only, errors)

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/encoding.py" in force_text
      80.                 s = six.text_type(bytes(s), encoding, errors)

    Exception Type: UnicodeEncodeError at /admin/messaging/thread/2/change/
    Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xc5' in position 35: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: you can define __unicode__ function in your models.

Comment: I do not have access to the models as it is from an external app, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Could you add the entire traceback?

Comment: @trinchet just updated it

Comment: Could you post the code of the model you are trying to edit/see here /admin/messaging/thread/2/change/ ?

Comment: I've just updated the relevant models, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your model:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Thread(models.Model):
     ...
```

and update the **str** method of this class to:

```
class Tour(models.Model):
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} by {1}".format(self.tour_name.encode('utf8'), self.tour_guide)
```

You also need to be sure the representation of UserProfile is encoded to `utf8`

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Tried and got a slightly longer error: ` 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 35: ordinal not in range(128). You passed in <django.forms.boundfield.BoundField object at 0x7fac68f5e550> (<class 'django.forms.boundfield.BoundField'>)`

Comment: Please add the entire traceback

Comment: I've solved the same issue. In my case I was running my script in a Docker container with a different Python version (3.6.9) that I used to develop and test it (3.7.5). So, now I've installed the same version into the container and don't get this error anymore. I hope this would be useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

try this: (u"" from unicode strings) i think it might be the problem

```
def __str__(self):
    return u"{0} by {1}".format(self.tour_name, self.tour_guide)
```